# Ruby 2.1.1 with RVM: Getting libyaml errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I would like to use `Ruby 2.1.1p76` and `Rails 4.1.0beta1`. I am getting some errors with RVM. I was using Ruby 2.0.0 and Rails 4.0.0. I upgraded to OS X Mavericks 10.9.2 and needed to reload everything.

Anyway, these are the commands I am running.

```
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
```

This installs successfully. Then I run this command to install rails.

```
sudo gem install rails
```

I get the following errors, says it is looking for libyaml.

```
/Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/yaml.rb:4:in `<top (required)>':
It seems your ruby installation is missing psych (for YAML output).
To eliminate this warning, please install libyaml and reinstall your ruby.
/Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': dlopen(/Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-darwin13.0/psych.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libyaml-0.2.dylib (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-darwin13.0/psych.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-darwin13.0/psych.bundle
      from /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
      from /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
      from /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
      from /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
      from /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/yaml.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
      from /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
      from /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
      from /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems.rb:616:in `load_yaml'
      from /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/config_file.rb:328:in `load_file'
      from /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/config_file.rb:197:in `initialize'
      from /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:74:in `new'
      from /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:74:in `do_configuration'
      from /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:39:in `run'
      from /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin/gem:21:in `<main>'
```

So, I run this command which is deprecated.

```
rvm pkg install libyaml
```

This gives me a deprecation warning and says to check out autolibs.

So I correct and verify both.

```
brew install libyaml
##
Warning: libyaml-0.1.4 already installed
```

more...

```
brew info libyaml
##
libyaml: stable 0.1.5 (bottled)
http://pyyaml.org/wiki/LibYAML
/usr/local/Cellar/libyaml/0.1.4 (7 files, 344K) *
  Built from source
From: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/commits/master/Library/Formula/libyaml.rb
==> Options
--universal
```

Install autolibs.

```
rvm get stable --autolibs=enable
rvm install ruby
rvm --default use ruby-2.1.1
```

Then, I get the same error.

```
Using /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1
/Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/yaml.rb:4:in `<top (required)>':
It seems your ruby installation is missing psych (for YAML output).
To eliminate this warning, please install libyaml and reinstall your ruby.
```

Answer (score 12):

```
brew unlink libyaml && brew link libyaml
```

https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/2689